# htaccess redirect and display website pages as sub-domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to redirect user profile pages to subdomains so every user would have his own subdomain. For example:

`example.com/user/username` redirect to to `username.example.com` and disaply the content of `example.com/user/username`

I have already set wildcard:

```
*.example.com
```

so now all subdomains show the content of example.com, but how to make it show use profile pages instead of homepage?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to show profile pages and there's no additional user content, try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)\.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ example.com/user/%1
```